# How to find nixpkgs revision where macos/darwin binary cache is built?

Tags: macos, haskell, devops, nix, nixos

I'd like to pin nixpkgs to a quite fresh revision, say, Haskell LTS-12.9 or something. And I want to use nix-build for MacOS (Darwin) builds.

The problem is there is no binary cache for most of Haskell packages, and the build takes ages to complete (on MacOS).

How could I find "optimal" nixpkgs revision, which is recent enough to contain software versions I need, but old enough for binary caches to be available for Linux and MacOS?

Comment: The nixpkgs-unstable branch is typically a little bit behind master (unless there are failing tests holding things up). Is that not recent enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the built versions of nixpkgs on [status.nixos.org](https://status.nixos.org/)

You'll probably want to use a revision of `nixpkgs-18.09-darwin` or `nixpkgs-unstable`.

---

You can then fetch nixpkgs like so

```
builtins.fetchGit {
  name = "nixpkgs";
  url = "https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs.git";
  rev = "6ec64973bc3a48b0c54d11c782e8b88b550a8eab";
  ref = "release-18.09";
})
```

The `ref` attribute is required when the revision isn't under the default branch - typically `master`.

A note [in the Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-builtins) describes it as follows:

> **Note:** It is nice to always specify the branch which a revision belongs to. Without the branch being specified, the fetcher might fail if the default branch changes. Additionally, it can be confusing to try a commit from a non-default branch and see the fetch fail. If the branch is specified the fault is much more obvious.

I suppose this behavior is inspired by a workaround in the Git protocol, that you can only specify refs for fetching, but not arbitrary commits, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it right. Now HowOldIs app shows 6ec64973bc3a48b0c54d11c782e8b88b550a8eab as latest nixpkgs-18.09-darwin commit. I use this to import packages:
    import (builtins.fetchGit {
      name = "lts-12.9";
      url = https://github.com/nixos/nixpkgs/;
      rev = "6ec64973bc3a48b0c54d11c782e8b88b550a8eab";
    }) {};
nix-build says fatal: not a tree object
error: program 'git' failed with exit code 128

Comment: I'd argue you got it right, Nix got it wrong. [Relevant issue](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2431)